# Codeigniter joining multiple ids and displaying to a view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, model

I'm stuck on something and would appreciate some help from you guys. I am building a fantasy game where I have fantasy team table with the below structure where each player will be saved with a unique ID generated from players table. Here is my player table

```
playerID  | playerName       | teamID  | value | point
13          peter Cech            2         8       0
15          Fernando Torres       2         9       0
```

and here is my fantasyteam table

```
teamID |  fantasyteam     | userID | GK1 | GK2 | DEF1 | DEF2 | MID1 | MID2 | FWD1 | FWD2
95        Washindi FC          1      13     2     3       6      7     12      15    18
```

what I want to achieve is joining `fantansyteam` table with player table in which the keys will be the ids of players in fantasy team table. Here is my model :-

```
            function get_fantansy_team($userID){
            $where=array(
            'userID'=>$userID,

            );
            $this->db->select();
            $this->db->from('fantansyteams AS FT');
            $this->db->join('player AS P1', 'FT.GK2= P1.playerID');
            $this->db->join('player AS P2', 'FT.GK1= P2.playerID','left outer');
            $this->db->where('FT.userID', $userID);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();


            }
```

Here is my controller :-

```
public function user($userID)
   {
     $this->load->model('team_model');
     $data['myteam']=$this->team_model->get_fantansy_team($userID);
         $this->load->view('myteam_view',$data);    
   }
```

And here is my view :-

```
     <?php  echo   "<pre>" ;print_r($myteam);echo "</pre>" ;?>
    <?php foreach($myteam as $player):
        echo $player['GK1'] ;
        echo $player['playerName'] ;
    endforeach;?>
```

Can someone help me how to display user team with the `playerName` and other fields in my view?

Comment: What should be your probable outcome / result?

Comment: @Nil'z, i have edited the codes and controller and view codes are now added. but the actual problem i think is in a model because in my view if i echo playerName it only displays GK1 name. my question is how do i query the database using join so as i can display each player's name. Thanks again for helping out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and see what you get:

```
function get_fantansy_team($userID){
    $where=array(
        'userID'=>$userID,
    );
    $this->db->select('P1.playerName, P2.playerName, FT.fantasyteam');
    $this->db->from('fantasyteam AS FT'); //corrected table name
    $this->db->join('player AS P1', 'FT.GK2= P1.playerID');
    $this->db->join('player AS P2', 'FT.GK1= P2.playerID','left outer');
    $this->db->where('FT.userID', $userID);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nilz, i think were close, i have this error Unknown column 'FT.fantansyteams' in 'field list' but when i remove FT.fantasyteam only  the first player is returned. please can u help me on how to display each player name on my view.Thanks again :-)

Comment: is your table name `fantansyteams / fantansyteam` ?

Comment: you have misspelled the table name in model `fantansyteams`